# Boss is unable to attend resignation meeting

Tags: resignation

I tried to schedule a meeting for today to give my boss my resignation letter. Unfortunately he is very busy and hasn't seen the email yet.

My manager said that the boss would be away for the rest of the day in a meeting

I sent another email to my boss asking him to call me when he is available at the advice of my manager.

I already have my resignation letter typed up and dated with the one month notice required in my contract

My concern is the extra day that I would have to add since I will have to do the meeting tomorrow

Comment: Yes they are separate

Comment: The boss hired me and the manager is for day to day stuff

Comment: Is editing the letter and printing a new one a problem?

Comment: 1. Does your email contain your resignation notice?  2. If it does, then I'd start my countdown today rather than whenever the boss gets your typed resignation letter. Does what I say about starting the countdown from the date of your email make sense in your country? 3.  Is there anything in terms of law or custom in your country that says that only a typed resignation letter that the boss hack acknowledged as having read counts as a resignation notice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would verbally inform your manager of what you are doing first. Then I'd email the resignation letter to the boss and to the manager at the end of the day today. You can discuss it with him in person at a later date when he is available. I don't think there is anything wrong with emailing your resignation, especially if it is to someone you don't see on a regular basis.

If you're leaving it is what it is. You have to do it. A month is a very large amount of notice to give(Edit: at least from my experience in the USA, sounds like other countries have different standards for amount of notice).  If you're actually hoping for a counter offer to get you to stay, then I'd probably wait until tomorrow and discuss in person.

Comment: +1 but minor comment: Notice periods probably vary depending on location and job type. A month is standard in all the jobs I've had in the UK (mostly IT sector) and mandatory notice period may increase with length of service or seniority.

Comment: They go up to 3-6 months in some places.  A month notice period is not terribly burdensome.

Comment: We have a 15 working days period in the company (Spain) but a financial bonus when you notify the management 1 month beforehand.

Comment: I'd agree with the above - the USA tends to use 2 weeks, but in the UK it's often stipulated as a longer period for professional jobs (ie salaried positions and graduate/professional roles). Many top out at 3 or even 6 months periods, and 1 is certainly considered normal rather than excessive.